# I want to know for which binary tree does it support?

Tags: data-structures

In which case(or for which binary tree) the last character of preorder and inorder are same(or 1st of post and inorder) ?

As per me for a binary tree it follows the above but i encounter a tree for which it is not supporting...

[i was not allowed to put picture here so m explaining the tree]

A is the root
B,C are child of A respectively
E,F are of B
G is left child of C

in the above description you can get the last char of preorder and inorder are not same.

I want to know for which binary tree does it support  ?

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is skew Tree**.

Preorder means the following:

```
First the Root,Then the Left subtree and then the right subtree.
```

Inorder means the following:

```
First the left subtree,then the Root and then the right subtree.
```

**Now consider a skew tree which has no left child anywhere.This means we might as well completely ignore the Left subtree part of the two definitions above and what we get is:**

```
The Root and then the right subtree.
```

**In both cases.**

Hence the last character(in fact all characters) of a binary tree **which is skew and has no left child anywhere** is same for preorder and inorder.

Post order means the following:

```
First the left subtree,then the right subtree and then the root
```

**Now consider a skew tree which has no right child anywhere.This means we might as well completely ignore the right subtree part of the two definitions of postorder and inorder and what we get is:**

```
The left subtree and then the root.
```

**in both cases**

Hence the first character(in fact all characters) of a binary tree **which is skew and has no right child anywhere** is same for postorder and inorder.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But if you take a scenario root-A, B,C are left n right child of A,  D,E are child of B. In this case the last char of inorder and preorder are same but the given tree is not skew tree.
if a question is asked like-
If lastin and lastpre are the last char of inorder and preorder of a BINARY TREE then which is true ?
Options:    a> lastin=lastpre    b>lastin != lastpre
If a is the correct opt then complete binary tree is also a binary tree for which it is not satisfying.
if b then for skew tree it satisfies and skew tree is also a binary tree.
please clear this confusion

Comment: @ashish Only two options are there?

Comment: @ashish If something else is mentioned with options,do tell me.

Comment: @ashish Also if possible,kindly tell me the entire question or post a link to the question.

Comment: thank u for ur consideration :) 
Let LASTPOST, LASTIN and LASTPRE denote the last vertex visited in a postorder, inorder and preorder traversal. Respectively, of a complete binary tree. Which of the following is always true?
Options Given:
A> LASTIN = LASTPRE
B> LASTIN = LASTPOST
C> LASTPRE = LASTPOST
D> NONE

Comment: @ashish In some complete trees, option A is correct, in some complete trees option B is correct, there cannot be only one correct answer.

Comment: Thanks.....but m in dilema bcz these question was asked in GATE exam where you have to mark one option. But nyway good job.

Comment: @ashish In that case D is the only correct answer,my friend.

Comment: @ashish The reason is because for option a , option b , option c, we can easily find counter examples and therefore, option d is the most appropriate answer,.

Comment: thanks buddy. Posting some more questions if you know please answer it.